# How to create IIS section

Tags: c#, vb.net, security, iis

Hi I am trying to create a new location/security structure in the iis-config-file programmatically.

I see when I add it using IIS administration application it creates a structure like this:

```
<location path="Default FTP Server/VirtualDirectory">
  <system.ftpServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="administrators" permissions="Read, Write" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.ftpServer>
</location>
```

I have tried to find out how to do this, but most examples, especially on MSDN throws exceptions if the section is not defined.

As it is possible with the WMA, I am assuming it can be done in .Net also... 
So the question is:
How do you create this structure programmatically using .Net (either c# or vb.net)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually quite simple. Below is the code in VB (because I am implementing this in an old software we are running - which was developed in vb):

```
' I am running this in a win-Form (Test application) and so create
' a winform with a text field and name it txtPath in order to make this work
' Add reference to Microsoft.Web.Administration 
' which can be found here:
' C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll

If txtPath.Text = String.Empty Then
            Return
        End If

        ' Defining a string to hold the value of the text field
        Dim pathName As String = txtPath.Text

        ' Create the ServerManager object
        Dim serverManager As ServerManager = New ServerManager

        ' Create the configuration object using applicationHost.config file
        Dim config As Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration

        ' Get the section Default FTP Site/path (may or may not exist!)
        Dim authorizationSection As Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "Default FTP Site/" & pathName)

        ' Get the collection based on section
        Dim authorizationCollection As Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElementCollection = authorizationSection.GetCollection

        ' Define an add element inside authorization
        Dim addElement As Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement = authorizationCollection.CreateElement("add")

        ' Add attribute accessType
        addElement("accessType") = "Allow"

        ' Add attribute users (You can also use roles)
        ' Here I am using the same as the path name (virtual directory)
        addElement("users") = pathName

        ' Add attribute permissions
        addElement("permissions") = "Read, Write"

        ' Add element to the collection
        authorizationCollection.Add(addElement)

        ' Commit your defined data
        serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

The above code should give you this output:

```
<location path="Default FTP Site/TheNameYouStatedInTheTextField">
    <system.ftpServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <add accessType="Allow" users="TheNameYouStatedInTheTextField" permissions="Read, Write" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.ftpServer>
</location>
```

I hope this helps someone....

Answer (score 0):

You might look into [Configuration Section Designer Project](https://csd.codeplex.com/). This helps you to create custom sections in Visual studio very easily. If you really need to do it programmatically in your codebase, you might be able to dig around in their codebase to figure it out.